# Using O365 RST API how to post Video to O365 Video Portal

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, office-365-video-portal

I couldn't found a way to upload a video using O365 REST API [Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/video-rest-operations#video-operations)
please help me.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the O365 Video service and not Microsoft Stream (Stream doesn't have any APIs)? O365 Video is being retired - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/migrate-from-office-365

Comment: O365 video is like a temporary location, for a client need to move 7K videos to Stream, but for the stream there is no API available and for O365 Video it's available. and O365 is providing option to Migrate to Stream.

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation which you linked to, has a [REST API for uploading videos](https://docs.microsoft.com/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/video-rest-operations#upload-videos-to-a-channel).